# Posting Modal Form and displaying Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have a simple modal with a form I want to post for some database insertion. This is my code:

**Address View:**

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Address</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <!-- Modal content-->

            @{Html.RenderAction("_AddMemberAddress", "MemberData");}
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

**Modal Partial View:**

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("_AddMemberAddress", "MemberData", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal"}))
    {           
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="email">Line 1:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Line1, new { @class = "form-control" , placeholder = "Line1"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=> x.Line1)                  
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>

    }
```

**Controller is Basic:**

```
  public PartialViewResult _AddMemberAddress(MemberAddressViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Save
        }
        viewModel.AddressTypes = _memberAddressService.GetAddressType();
        return PartialView(viewModel);
    }
```

Now This is fairly simple and standard if this was a regular form, but I want it to be modal just to be `fancy` and try new things. The problem is that when the Validation comes back, if its no valid of course, it redirects to my empty partial view. I want to display the validation message inside the modal and I have no idea how to do this. Any help would be great.

Comment: Depends a bit on what you want to do if the form is valid, but you will need ajax to post the form, then if not valid, return the view and replace the contents of your modal

Comment: Well if its valid I would just redirect to the page where the addresses are listed, so that's no prob. The validation one is the issue. I saw some Ajax methods but I am a bit lost as its not my forte.

Comment: Ajax calls do not redirect (they stay on the same page) so you cant have it both ways (although you could return `null` if its valid and do a redirect in the browser (`location.href=`)). But its not clear if the view the modal is on is the list of address (in which case you would just update the current page with the form values if the model was valid and saved)

Answer (score 0):

This is a common confusion. Just because your form is in a partial view doesn't mean that the response from the server when posted will be placed into the same spot. Once the rendered HTML document has been delivered to the client, there's no concept of "partial views". It's just an HTML document, and posting a form is going to cause the browser to replace the *entire* page with the response from that request.

The only way around that is to post your form with AJAX, which won't change the page in the browser. However, then, it's on you to handle the response from the server and *do something with it*. You could post to this action that returns a partial, for example, but in your AJAX success block, you'll have to manually insert the returned HTML where you want it go in the existing page.